# How can I backup my Fennec profile, properly?

Tags: backup, firefox-for-android

I need to backup my Firefox/Fennec profile folder.

One way to achive that is by copying it into an external storage. Although, I'm affraid restoring it will not be easy, due to file permissions.

Comment: You can only backup it personally if you have root access. Assuming you do have it, use tar command to backup the content of Firefox's data directory. As for preserving file permissions and Selinux context, recursively search for files using find or ls, and than save each file's permissions  and security context in a  dedicated file - - to be used as a central repository of file permissions. Done.

Comment: That's the gist... I just can't figure out the dedicated file part. Would you mind creating an answer?